# Read content as integer of empty XML element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I encountered a problem while parsing XML in C# with XMLReader.

Here is an example:

```
string text = xNode.ReadElementContentAsString().Length > 0 ? xBonusesNode.ReadElementContentAsString() : null;
int nmb = xNode.ReadElementContentAsInt();
```

So, where I'm trying to get string value there is simple inline if statement to check if element has data or not.

How can I do something similar with integer? Or how to catch exception correctly and in best way, for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) like this:

```
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(xNode.ReadElementContentAsString, out number);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = xNode.ReadElementContentAsString().Length > 0 ? xBonusesNode.ReadElementContentAsString() : null;
Int32.TryParse(text,out myInt);
```

Should work.

I'm not sure whether the xml library supports nullable types (int?) but the above should work anyway - basically I'm reading it as a string then trying to parse it. If TryParse fails myInt will remain as it was before (and tryParse returns 'false')

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Stefan P. was first.